# Unable to figure out pointers behaviour

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm unable to figure out why `temp->next=NULL` is breaking the original linked list

My code here :

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

Node* createNode(int data)
{
    Node* temp=new Node;
    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=NULL;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
Node* root=createNode(1);
root->next=createNode(2);
root->next->next=createNode(3);
display(root);
cout<<"\nAddress of root = "<<&root<<"-> "<<&(root->next)<<"-> "<<&(root->next->next);

Node* temp=root;
temp->next=NULL;  //Trying to set next pointer to Null in temp list but instead it is impacting the original list by nullifying the next node. Why is it so ?
display(temp);
cout<<"\nAddress of temp = "<<&temp<<"-> "<<&(temp->next);
display(root);  // Original list broke
}
```

Output:

```
Linked list => 1->2->3
Address of root = 0x7ffd3afbc2f0-> 0x5605aff6cc28-> 0x5605aff6cc48
Linked list => 1
Address of temp = 0x7ffd3afbc2f8-> 0x5605aff6cc28
Linked list => 1
```

Comment: It's not clear what you *expect* to happen when you set a root's `next` to null, but you now have a list with only the root element. And a bunch of leaks.

Comment: Perhaps you are confused by `Node* temp=root;`. You now have two pointers to the same list. It does not create a copy of the list. If you change the list through either pointer, using the the other pointer will reflect those changes.

Comment: Post a [MCVE]..

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm not setting root's next to null. I'm setting temp's next to null. Both are different objects, you can see the addresses are different. root (0x7ffd3afbc2f0) and temp(0x7ffd3afbc2f8). I wanted to change temp's next to NULL without impacting root list.

Comment: @DwayneSmith Those two *pointers* have different address, but they point to the same list. Those are not the addresses of lists, but of pointers to lists. Try printing `root` and `temp` instead and you will see they have the same value. `root->next` and `temp->next` are the same object in every sense.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: The first pointer i.e. temp and root are both different pointers with same content and next pointer. I understand that `temp->next` points to `root->next` but why is it that I'm unable to change next pointer to 
 point to the Null in temp list.

Comment: @DwayneSmith It's not just that they point to the same object, they are both the same pointer. Not equivalent pointers, but literally the same pointer.

Comment: By setting temp->next to NULL you create memory leak as you needed that pointer to delete Node 2 when you come to that

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: So you mean that `Node* temp=root;` will create a temp pointer which is nothing but a reference to `root`. If it is the case then why they both have different memory addresses ?  No doubt that they further point to same memory location i.e. both points to the second node in root list.

Comment: `&root` is the address of the *variable* `root`. This is not the same as the *value* of `root`, which is the address of the root node.

Comment: @DwayneSmith You simply have two pointers and they have the same value. They both point to the same memory address where your root node lies. It's important to make the distinction between the value of a pointer (*what* it points to) and *it's* address, the address that the pointer occupies in memory. Consider that a pointer requires some amount of memory to store the address it points to, and it's the address of that storage that `&` returns. It's also important to make the distinction that `temp` doesn't refer to `root`. Rather, it refers to the same thing `root` did when you assigned it.

Comment: @DwayneSmith Imagine writing down your home address first in your father's phone book ("root") and then in your cousin's phone book ("temp"). It's not strange (I hope) that those two phone books are not in the same place at the same time, but both contain the same value for your home address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a pointer `int* ptr;` and an integer `int var;`. In the same way `&var` is the address of the integer and is distinct from it's value, `&ptr` is the address of the pointer and is distinct from it's value (*what* it points to).

The expression `Node* temp=root;` is creating a pointer `temp` with the same value as `root`, they refer to the same object. `temp` and `root` are different objects and have different address (`&root` and `&temp` are different), but they have the same value (`root` and `temp` are equal). As such `temp->next` and `root->next` are the same pointer. Changing one will change the other.

In your example, there only ever exists one linked list, to which `root` and `temp` both refer.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot. But how should I create a separate copy with second pointer pointing to Null in temp ?

Comment: @DwayneSmith That may work, but you'll just be pushing the problem back. What happens when you want to change that node's `next`? Conceptually, it seems you are trying to copy the list. If that's the case, you should make a deep copy of the entire list such that each list only refers to it's own nodes. Consider encapsulating the list in a proper type with value semantics. You'll need to understand the very important [rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Unless this is for educational purposes, just use the standard containers like `std::vector`.

Comment: temp=createNode(1);

Comment: @DwayneSmith I think I may have misunderstood your comment when I replied. It's not clear to me how you would copy a node into a new list. What `Node` is and how they are created is not shown. You'll need to create a new `Node` and copy over the state of the node pointed to by `root` to that new node.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Thanks for getting back. I've updated the Node structure. Please guide me accordingly. Basically I'm just using new operator for creating new nodes with the given data passed into a function.

Comment: @DwayneSmith In that case, if you want to rely on the existing infrastructure, you need to create a new node and copy `root->data` to `temp->data`. The key is that `temp` and `root` need to point to different `Node` instances. Beware that this is starting to go beyond the scope of the question. If you continue to have problems, you should post a new question about the new problem, going through the regular process which includes preforming your own research, verifying that similar questions haven't already been asked and showing your efforts and attempts.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers just point at a location in memory, hence their name. When you do this:

```
Node* temp=root;
```

you create a pointer `temp` pointing at the same memory location as the pointer `root`. So this:

```
temp->next=NULL;
```

and this:

```
root->next=NULL;
```

do the exact same thing, because `temp->next` and `root->next` are the same.